# Iphone should block 0 number in the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, keyboard

I've been writting iphone application in xcode, there is a form that contain phone number field. It must be contain 10 digits. If the user press 0 firstly in the keyboard, application must not write it.

For instance, phone number 05551234567, user can be only write 5551234567. If the user press 0, nothing happen.

Comment: ...and What is question ?Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following method.

by using below method user cannot enter 0 in textfield

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)TextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                return NO;

            }
        }


    return YES;
}
```

And if you want that user cannot enter 0 only first place then use method like below

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)TextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

        NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"123456789"];

    if ([TextField.text length]<=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++)
        {
            unichar c = [string characterAtIndex:i];
            if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c])
            {
                return NO;

            }
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 9):

First of all you should use

```
textView.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypePhonePad
```

to choose the correct type of keyboard, so that you will be able to enter just numbers.

Secondly you must implement a `UITextViewDelegate`, set it as the text view delegate and implement a custom

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

that will check if you are trying to insert a 0 at the beginning of the content and return `NO` in that case.

If you are using a `UITextField` everything is the same, the only diffeference is that you will use `UITextFieldDelegate` and implement

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
```